# Rails 4 Rspec test session when assigned in spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

In my test i assign session to a specific value but when i run the test and print from my app controller, the session is nil. Any idea how should i do this ?

Here is my spec :

```
RSpec.describe "welcome/index.html.haml", type: :view do
  before(:each) do
    session[:followed_repos] = ["rails/rails"]
  end

  context "when visitor tracked repositories" do
    it "should see tracked repository list" do
      visit root_path
      expect(page).to have_no_content("You are tracking 0 repositories. Search for more here")
      expect(page).to render_template(:partial => "_tracked_repo")
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my controller where i print the value :

```
  def index
    puts session[:followed_repos].inspect
  end
```

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 answers that might help people trying to use session in type: :view :

1. You can use that gem: [rack_session_access](https://github.com/railsware/rack_session_access)
2. You have no other choice then reproduce all the needed steps to get the session you need